# How do I update data bindings once a variable changes value in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a $scope variable selectedUser, which is set when a user in a list is clicked. I update the properties of selectedUser and send a request to the backend updating the user with the matching id. Of course in the ng-repeat that lists all users, the property is updating just fine, because upon completion of the update, I run a User.get() which re-initializes the ng-repeat list withthe new data. It seems, however, that when I then update the selectedUser variable with the same user but with its newly set properties,  the binding to selectedUser does not update.

In essence, my question is: If a $scope variable is changed after page load, how do i get the binding (or whatever you refer to the double curly braces in a view as) to update with the new value?

Again, the $scope.selectedUser object is updated, but {{selectedUser.aProperty}} is not updating.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Matt, you might need to post some code -- based on what you're describing it should 'just work'.  It might be that you're updating the User in a child scope and the page is bound to a parent scope.

Comment: I think you're right about the child scope. How do I propagate a change through all controllers. As in, up to the top controller and then down to all child controllers that use the variable I'm changing the value of?

Comment: To confirm, I would use the [Batarang chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) and check the user value in each scope after it's updated to see if some scopes still have a reference to the old `User`.

Comment: So that is the case. I'm still unsure of how to propagate the change to all references no matter what scope the change is made in. There are a few instances in this project where I run into this scenario. Any tips?

Comment: I would suggest not setting the User directly when updating (either from any child controller or from inline expressions in the view), but use a setter function declared in the same controller as where the user is initially set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you run into this issue (as per my comments) when you update a model in a child scope, but the view reference is bound to a parent scope.

I've created an artificial example of that sort of issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9C4M4oCNdywOOgUgrTSQ?p=preview).

When you change an object from a child scope like below, the child scope gets the new object, but the parent scope retains it's old copy, and any changes from the child scope now only touch the new object.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="RootCtrl">
    <!-- this is bound to my RootCtrl scope -->
    <h1>{{user.name}} ({{user.id}})</h1>
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
      <!-- this will inherit it's value from RootCtrl's scope until
           we overwrite it: -->
      <b>Name:</b> {{user.name}}
      <b>Id:</b> {{user.id}}
      <button ng-click="newUser()">New Id</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'John',
    id: 12
  };
})
.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
  /* if you move this method to the parent scope,
   * both should update as expected. */
  $scope.newUser = function() {
    $scope.user  = { id: 100, name: 'Bob' };
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm back at work tomorrow to give your suggestion a try. If it works I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: The setter function in the top level controller did the trick. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Ussualy AngularJS should update all the bound elements when the scope changes in an event handler but in the case it doesn't you can manually call `$scope.$apply()`.

Also, check [this post about when to use $scope.$apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29) in your module's lifecycle.